# Can't connect to site in IIS through DNS Alias, but can connect through localhost

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, alias

I have a site in IIS configured and visible over localhost.
I have also set up an CNAME Alias within the DNS to point to this server as 'main' and set up the bindings for the site with 'main' over port 80.
From the server the site is configured on, I am able to view the site as Localhost, and can ping the Alias, which returns the correct server, but if i try and navigate to 'main', I get the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Would this be a problem with the Alias not being configured correctly, or more likely a problems with the bindings not pointing to the correct directories?

The server running the site is Windows Server 2012 R2 and the IIS version is IIS8

Comment: I'd check that the server is listening on the desired ip address with `netstat -a`, then try to connect to the default website using the ip address instead of the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After prompting from @simlev, running `netstat -a` showed that the IP address I was expecting was not present in the list listening to port 80.

Running `netsh http show iplisten` gave me the IP Listen List, which also was missing my external IP address, only `127.0.0.1`

After running `netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=X.X.X.X` to add the IP address of my server, the site can now be accessed through both localhost and `main`